# Accepting user input and incoming connections in the same while loop

Tags: c, sockets

I'm writing a socket based application in C which needs to take user input and perform various tasks based on them. Also the program opens a server and needs to wait for incoming connections.

Here's the code that does this part,

```
while(1)
{

    if((sockClient = accept(sockServer, (struct sockaddr*)&client, (socklen_t *)&len)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Accept failed: ");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        send(sockClient, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
        printf("Connected to client : %s\n", inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr));
    }

    ......
    ......
}
```

Now in the same infinite loop, I need to take user input and process them accordingly. This is the code that does that.

```
char usrInputStr[256];
printf("Enter Instruction: ");
scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", usrInputStr);
memcpy(cmdHist[histCount], usrInputStr, strlen(usrInputStr));
histCount++;

char** currentTokens = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*256);
for(int i=0; i<256; i++)
{
    currentTokens[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
}

processInstruction(usrInputStr, currentTokens);
```

The issue is that this functionality is not behaving as expected. When I take off the code for accept call, the user input is processed correctly. Can someone tell me how to restructure this code to make both work together.

Comment: accept is a blocking call. Also, there is no need to cast the result of malloc.

Comment: Hint : look at `poll` or `select` functions ;)

Comment: "The issue is that this functionality is not behaving as expected"  How exactly?  What do you expect it to do, and what is it actually doing?  Also, it's hard to tell what's going on without both pieces of code in context.

Answer (score 0):

A nice basic example to understand network interaction is in the glibc documentation, one for [server](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Server-Example.html) and another for [client](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Byte-Stream-Example.html#Byte-Stream-Example)